# python numpy arange dtpye? why converting to integer was zero

Tags: python, numpy

x = np.arange(0.3, 12.5, 0.6)

print(x)

[  0.3   0.9   1.5   2.1   2.7   3.3   3.9   4.5   5.1   5.7   6.3   6.9  7.5   8.1   8.7   9.3   9.9  10.5  11.1  11.7  12.3]

x = np.arange(0.3, 12.5, 0.6,int)

print(x)

[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

Comment: Due to floating point rounding, even `np.arange(0.3, 12.5, 0.6).astype(int)` can be produce surprises.

Comment: First of all thank you, I want to know exactly what the cause is.dtype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's skip the complexity of a float step, and use a simple integer start and stop:

```
In [141]: np.arange(0,5)
Out[141]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [142]: np.arange(0,5, dtype=int)
Out[142]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [143]: np.arange(0,5, dtype=float)
Out[143]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.])
In [144]: np.arange(0,5, dtype=complex)
Out[144]: array([0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 2.+0.j, 3.+0.j, 4.+0.j])
In [145]: np.arange(0,5, dtype='datetime64[D]')
Out[145]: 
array(['1970-01-01', '1970-01-02', '1970-01-03', '1970-01-04',
       '1970-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Even `bool` work, within a certain range:

```
In [149]: np.arange(0,1, dtype=bool)
Out[149]: array([False])
In [150]: np.arange(0,2, dtype=bool)
Out[150]: array([False,  True])
In [151]: np.arange(0,3, dtype=bool)
ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
In [156]: np.arange(0,3).astype(bool)
Out[156]: array([False,  True,  True])
```

There are 2 possible boolean values, so asking for more should produce some sort of error.

`arange` is compiled code, so we can't readily examine its logic (but you are welcome to search for the C code on github).

The examples show that it does, in some sense convert the parameters into the corresponding `dtype`, and perform an iteration on that.  It doesn't simply generate the range and convert to dtype at the end.

Comment: thank you, then I will do the float type .astype (int) as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

When `dtype = int` is specified, it is converting the start, stop and step into the same.

So, it becomes `int(start), int(stop), int(step)`.

Hence, in your case, when dtype = int is specified, the start and step remain 0 and you get an array full of 0s.

This problem has been discussed with explanation here:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2457

Comment: First of all thank you, I want to know exactly what the cause is. dtype?

Comment: I suppose, yes.