# NumPy: Where in the source code are `arange` and `array` functions defined?

Tags: python, numpy

I was looking for the source code for the `arange` and `array` functions in NumPy, but I couldn't find it: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22def+arange%22+path%3Anumpy%2Fcore&type=

Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Quick tip: if it says `<built-in function whatever>`, that means it's in C, not Python. You're not going to find a `def` statement for it.

Comment: numpy is compiled C under the hood is that really what you are after?

Comment: @Julien: I don't think there's any C++. It's Python, C, and Fortran.

Comment: @user2357112 noted, I tend to add ++ anywhere without really paying attention :)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the tip! Though I didn't see "built-in" indicated for `array`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array.

Comment: `type(np.arange)` will show `builtin` as opposed to`function`.

Comment: Most of us are content to deduce their behavior from examples and trial and error.  A recent example with `arange`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171141/python-numpy-arange-dtpye-why-converting-to-integer-was-zero.  Documentation is sufficient for the common cases.  The main problem area with `np.array` is when the input lists are not regular, creating object dtype arrays or raising errors.

Comment: While this question is not great, it has legitimate non-trivial answers that demonstrate the relative difficulty some beginners have in digging through the numpy code.

Comment: @Julien Ah okay, perhaps this is it? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/820765d762513510a8e46f108e8bc8b366127f8f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2939

Comment: Cool, just saw the answers...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`numpy.array` and `numpy.arange` are written in C. You can tell because they say "built-in" when you look at them:

```
>>> numpy.array
<built-in function array>
>>> numpy.arange
<built-in function arange>
```

That means there's no `def` statement. Instead, we look at what module they come from:

```
>>> numpy.array.__module__
'numpy.core.multiarray'
>>> numpy.arange.__module__
'numpy.core.multiarray'
```

navigate to the corresponding [source file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c), and take a look at the [array](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4298) controlling the module's exported functions:

```
{"array",
    (PyCFunction)_array_fromobject,
    METH_VARARGS|METH_KEYWORDS, NULL},
...
{"arange",
    (PyCFunction)array_arange,
    METH_VARARGS|METH_KEYWORDS, NULL},
```

`numpy.array` and `numpy.arange` correspond to `_array_fromobject` and `array_arange` in that file. That's not where all the work happens, though. You'll need to keep digging to find all the relevant code.

Comment: A followup if you don't mind: why is it we can refer `arange` simply as `numpy.arange`, instead of `numpy.core.multiarray.arange`? It seems to work with `nonzero` as well, which is not a builtin: `numpy.nonzero` just works, no need to say `numpy.core.nonzero`. However, this is not always possible, as `matplotlib.plot` does not work, and we have to say `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`.

Comment: @FreshAir, use the name that's given in the docs.  It all comes down to how various modules are imported.  Sometimes `import numpy as np` is enough.  Sometimes you have to use something like `from scipy import sparse`.

Answer (score 2):

These are defined in multiarraymodule.c:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/820765d762513510a8e46f108e8bc8b366127f8f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4279

`array` function in Python is `_array_fromobject()` in C, and `arange` function in Python is `array_arange()` in C.